# freeswitch not accepting calls, tls invalid

Tags: freeswitch

i just made a fresh install for freeswitch on windows

wireshark show invites coming in on sip, but freeswitch show no activity

on startup freeswitch shows several errors, specifically

> 2016-08-16 16:37:08.919250 [DEBUG] sofia.c:4237 tls-verify-date [true]
>   2016-08-16 16:37:08.919250 [DEBUG] sofia.c:4237 tls-verify-policy
>   [none] 2016-08-16 16:37:08.919250 [ERR] sofia_glue.c:329 **Invalid
>   tls-verify-policy value: none** 2016-08-16 16:37:08.919250 [DEBUG]
>   sofia.c:4237 tls-verify-depth [2]

and

> 2016-08-16 16:37:15.260094 [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:390
>   Adding File Format 'G723' 2016-08-16 16:37:15.260094 [CRIT]
>   switch_loadable_module.c:1520 **Error Loading module C:/Program
>   Files/FreeSWITCH/mod/mod_png.dll
>   **dll open error [126l]**
>   ** 2016-08-16 16:37:15.261095 [CONSOLE] switch_loadable_module.c:1538 Successfully Loaded [mod_local_stream] 2016-08-16 16:37:15.261095
>   [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:338 Adding API Function
>   'local_stream'

(actually the dll load err happens for several dlls/mods)

i did some research and found that "none" may not be a valid option, so i commented out all settings to none (since its default anyway) , except for the ipv6 file

but the error still happens, should the ipv6 file be loaded? i believe it causes issues, moreover the documentation states that ipv6 is not supported on windows. so how can i disable it?

i appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've just found a workaround about the first issue:

The "tls-verify-policy" is a parameter defined in some sip profile. In my case it was a external profile in the route:

```
/usr/local/freeswitch/conf/sip_profiles/external.xml
```

And the parameter was defined as:

```
<param name="tls-verify-policy" value="none"/>
```

The problem is that the value "none" is not valid and according the documentation the possible values are `in/out/all/subjects_in/subjects_out/subjects_all`.

But if you don't want to verify any connection, you can leave it blank, as in:

```
<param name="tls-verify-policy" value=""/>
```

For the second issue see @NicholasBlasgen answer.

Comment: You can disable TLS on conf/sip_profiles/external.xml   
change ```<param name="tls" value="enabled"/>``` to    
```<param name="tls" value="disabled"/>```

Comment: @ArthurG That's if you want to disable TLS, but this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks I had the issue in ICTfax and your solution worked

Answer (score 0):

If you have no need for MOD_PNG, then best to just disable it.  That should be the quickest solution.  Look at `autoload_configs/modules.conf.xml` to be able to disable it.

The longer solution would be to identify why the linked library won't load.  I suspect there was a bug in it and it's likely been fixed by now.  You can also use Freeswitch's bug tracker to report a problem.